# Testing HTTP and HTTPS on Cucumber Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to fix a bug and the impossibility to reproduce it on my local environment is becoming a problem.

Cucumber might be able to help, but I couldn't find a way to make cucumber work for me. It is specifically about HTTP and HTTPS.

I use 4 different environments. Only production and the one below are HTTPS ones and my bug only happens there exactly because of the protocol/URL generation.

Is there a way to make cucumber work under HTTPS for a specific feature?

I hope it was clear enough, although I think it is still a bit vague.

Comment: *my bug only happens there exactly* - what is your bug?

Comment: What do you want to use to automate your tests, capybara ? webrat ? Cucumber is "just" the glue between your gherkin scenarios and your test code, it will support the capabilities of the automation library you use behind it.

Comment: As @Uzbekjon says, the bug is the real thing that'll we would be able to help you nail quickly, and help you setup tests to ensure it doesn't happen again. If you can provide details on what the bug is, we will able able to help.

Comment: Cucumber does not use http, https, tcp, udp, or any other network protocol. Some other part of your tooling does. Maybe it's Selenium. Once you figure out the right piece, you will find it easier to describe the problem. My suggestion is to always treat it like a defect with happens/should happen, steps to reproduce, errors, stack traces, and code.

Comment: @Uzbekjon: The user performs an action and, after that, there's a redirect. This redirect is a HTTP or HTTPS, depending on the environment. It works for HTTP environments, but not for HTTPS ones. For some reason it is not generating the URL correctly when HTTPS should be used.

Comment: @MarcLainez: I use capybara.

Comment: @DaveMcNulla: I have test scenarios for my development, but I don't have any tests for this situation that I described. If I change, in the code, to always use HTTPS they are all green, which makes accordingly to your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make capybara use `HTTPS` inside `cucumber tag hooks`. For instance:

```
@https
Scenario: redirect to another location
  Given I am seeing something
  When I do some action
  Then I should be directed to another location
```

Now the way to make it work is to use `cucumber hooks`.

```
# Use HTTPS host for specific scenario
Before('@https') do
  Capybara.app_host = some_https_location
end

# Revert back to HTTP host for future scenarios
After('@https') do
  Capybara.app_host = some_regular_http_location
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something of that sort. I will try to put it to test and will give a feedback about it.

Comment: It worked for what's intended to work. Thanks.

I found this link that might be useful for people using HTTPS and Capybara:
http://cowjumpedoverthecommodore64.blogspot.lu/2013/09/if-your-website-runs-under-ssl-than.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It makes your local server go live on the internet providing both http and https options. I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It will be helpful indeed, but not in this case. Our company policy would not allow that.